# VS Code Jupyter Notebook Session Cannot Generate Request

Tags: python, macos, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, image-classification

Doing an image classifier project on my Mac. Any cell I run after the

```
train_x=train_x/255.0
test_x=test_x/255.0
val_x=val_x/255.0
```

gives

```
Error: Session cannot generate requests
Error: Session cannot generate requests
at w.executeCodeCell (/Users/ethan/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2021.8.2041215044/out/client/extension.js:52:301310)
at w.execute (/Users/ethan/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2021.8.2041215044/out/client/extension.js:52:300703)
at w.start (/Users/ethan/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2021.8.2041215044/out/client/extension.js:52:296367)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
at async t.CellExecutionQueue.executeQueuedCells (/Users/ethan/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2021.8.2041215044/out/client/extension.js:52:311160)
at async t.CellExecutionQueue.start (/Users/ethan/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2021.8.2041215044/out/client/extension.js:52:310700)
```

How would I go about fixing this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try to update jupyter extension and restart the kernel.

> Error: Session cannot generate requests

Usually, this is caused by the kernel losing connection.